# LGPL library is linked statically to other LGPL library

Tags: licensing, open-source, lgpl

In commercial proprietary product `library1` is used which is under LGPL. According to LGPL `library1` is distributed separately as shared library. `library1` statically linked to other library `library2` which LGPL licensed as well. Is it ok distribute both libraries as single shared library? Or to meet LGPL requirements should both libraries be distributed separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To comply with the LGPL requirements, your users must have a way to replace the LGPL-licensed libraries with (compatible) versions of their own.

To replace `library2`, your users will have to recompile `library1` as well, but that is no hindrance to LGPL compliance, as they should have that possibility anyway.